# How to store matrix of class I made it in database?

Tags: c#

I have made 2 classes which name is Material class have 13 variable 
And bill class which have a material matrix like this

```
class Bill
{
     int id;
     int company_id;
     int bringer_id;
     string date;
     List<Material> items;           
}
```

now how can I store The matrix of The material in the bill table in the database

Answer (score 0):

Since a bill can contains mote than one materials, the relation between a bill and a material is 1 -> N, one to many. That being said, you should create a table, in which you will store this relation, between a material and a bill. It is evident that this can't be stored in the table of the bill. So, you have to create a table that would store for each bill it's materials.

For example, let that we have the bill with id=1023 and the materials with ids  178, 456, and 678, are associated with this bill. Then you should insert into this table three records.

```
------------------------------
Id  |  BillId  |  MaterialId
------------------------------
..  |  ......  |  ..........
123 |  1023    |  178
124 |  1023    |  456
125 |  1023    |  678
```

The table definition would be something like this (in TSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE BillMaterial
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BillId INT NOT NULL,
    MaterialId INT NOT NULL,
);
```

Furthermore, we have to declare two constraints. First, we should declare that the BillId would be a foreign key pointing to the Bill's table. Then, we should declare that MaterialId would be a foreign key pointing to the Material's key.

> how can I store The matrix of The material in the bill table in the
>   database

Personally, I would had picked the option of MERGE, in order to make multiple insertions in a transaction.  For doing so, we should create a stored procedure, which would take one parameter. This parameter would be a datatable. This datatable would have stored all the bill materials pairs. This implementation demands more work to be done, but I think it's more optimal compared to the other alternative, which would be to make a round trip to the database for each pair of bill and material and execute an insert statement. The latter *might can be avoided* using an ORM like Entity Framework, but I am not sure if this is possible. You have to search it.

Comment: ok I understand it Thank you for your help
one last think in this case I will have bill_material table in my database and he will hold for each bill a number of rows for example if i have a bill with 5 id and 1,2,3,4,5, material id it will store in the bill_material table in 5 rows is that ok for the database or it may overload or something like this and again Thank you for your usefull answer